# How to use the API PdfReader?

Tags: java, pdf

I am trying to flatten a pdf form file using java. I am using the PdfReader api. However  i am being shown these particular errors :

```
PdfReader cannot be resolved to a type
PdfStamper cannot be resolved to  a type
AcroFields cannot be resolved to a type .
```

Can anybody tell me, what Jar am i missing or any other possible reason for this one happening ?

This is the code :

```
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;

        public class FormFillAndMakeItFlattenPDF {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("SimpleRegistrationForm.pdf");
                    PdfStamper stamp2 = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("FormFillAndMakeItFlattenPDF.pdf"));
                    AcroFields form2 = stamp2.getAcroFields();
                    form2.setField("name", "your name");
                    form2.setField("address", "address");
                    form2.setField("postal_code", "code");
                    form2.setField("email", "youremail");
                    stamp2.setFormFlattening(true);
                    stamp2.close();
                }
                catch (Exception de) {
                    de.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are you importing? Can you provide a small code sample?

Comment: It seems you are missing iText jar. You can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/i/DownloadiText505jar.htm)

Comment: Sure i will show the code right away .

Comment: Thanks Shashank, lemme try that out.

Comment: and then add these import statements to your program. `import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;`

Comment: These particular imports dont work, but these ones work  :

import com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

Still, i am facing an error :

PdfStamper cannot be resolved to a type

The other errors are resolved .

Comment: Download [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/i/DownloadiText215jar.htm) older version. It has all the classes you need.

Comment: Good to know that you figured it out. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19424/discussion-between-the-dark-knight-and-shashank-kadne)